# Can't join 2 tables with a condition. Error 1064

Tags: mysql, sql

My task is to **select the list of orders (its ID, customer's Name and the date of an order) which were made in the second decade of February, 1997**

Here is my request:

```
select Orders.OrderID, Customers.CustomerName, Orders.OrderDate
from Orders
where Orders.OrderDate between '1997-02-10' and '1997-02-20'
join Customers
on Orders.CustomerID = Customers.CustomerID;
```

Where am I wrong?

Thank you all for help in advance.

Comment: `WHERE` comes after the `JOIN`... and `second decade of February, 1997` makes no sense whatsoever.  A decade is a period of 10 *years*, not 10 days.

Comment: `select ... from ... join ... where`

Comment: A decade is a period of 10 years.

Comment: Unlike English in Russian language decade means 10 days.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As indicated above in the comments, the `WHERE` condition must be written **after** the `JOIN` clause. Alternatively, you could as well throw in your `WHERE` condition as a part of the `JOIN`:

```
SELECT Orders.OrderID, Customers.CustomerName, Orders.OrderDate
       FROM Orders
       JOIN Customers
           ON  Orders.CustomerID = Customers.CustomerID
          AND  Orders.OrderDate between '1997-02-10' and '1997-02-20'
```

This could be particularly useful if you have several joins in the query and you want to filter out the unwanted records quickly - before applying any additional `JOIN`.

Comment: Thank you for your help.

Answer (score 0):

You must redefine your select statement:

```
select Orders.OrderID, Customers.CustomerName, Orders.OrderDate
from Orders
     join Customers
        on Orders.CustomerID = Customers.CustomerID;
where Orders.OrderDate between '1997-02-10' and '1997-02-20'
```

JOIN clause must be included in FROM section.

I would suggest to not use BETWEEN with dates.

```
select Orders.OrderID, Customers.CustomerName, Orders.OrderDate
from Orders
     join Customers
        on Orders.CustomerID = Customers.CustomerID;
where Orders.OrderDate >= cast('1997-02-10' as date) 
      and Orders.OrderDate cast('1997-02-20' as date);
```

Comment: Why should between be avoided? (I'm not disagreeing; I just think the answer could benefit from that explanation) (and updating your answer to fit your comment about decade)

Answer (score 0):

You have error in structure. You can use **WHERE** always after 
**FROM**. **ON** is part of from. Where filtering you result. Without result you can't use where:

```
select Orders.OrderID, Customers.CustomerName, Orders.OrderDate
    from Orders join Customers
    on Orders.CustomerID = Customers.CustomerID
    where Orders.OrderDate between '1997-02-10' and '1997-02-20';
```

Comment: Hi starko; your code might be correct, but with some context it would make a better answer; for example, you could explain how and why this proposed change would resolve the questioner's problem, perhaps including a link to the relevant documentation. That would make it more useful to them, and also more useful to other site readers who are looking for solutions to similar problems.

Comment: Thanks for your opininon. In next time i will write more about my proposal to answer. You are right, only code not help to much. Better answer is when i describe my proposal and add some documentation link. Many thanks for help

Comment: You don't have to wait for next time - in this site you're encouraged to [edit] your questions and answers to improve then add much as possible.